# What happens when a Rails asset is requested with a digest that doesn't match the manifest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I understand that, when pushing to production, Rails generates digests for assets, so that `application.js` will become `application-2695540c610db8087315134277d8afe6.js`. The digest/fingerprint is added to a manifest file so that Rails can keep track of them.

My question is: what happens if you request an asset with a different digest?

Please note that our app is set up so that Rails serves all assets, which then get cached by our CDN (which fronts all requests). From our observations, assets requested with the correct digest are served immediately, while others take time, which have us think that they might be compiled live.

Answer (score 0):

The digests help with caching issues. If a user has already requested the previous digested asset then it will be cached on their machine. If for some reason the page tries to call that version of the asset then the user will be served the cached version. Otherwise if the asset is not cached on the users machine and the page tries to fetch it, the asset would be unreadable as it no longer exists.

Comment: My question is more about what happens in the Rails backend when a user requests an asset with a different digest, not what happens in the client.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of pre-compiled assets is that they are just files in the file system. If you are not deleting your old assets (ie, by creating a new directory for each deploy), they are still there, and the requests for them will succeed.

If you delete your old assets, then the server will respond with a 404 unless you have `config.assets.compile` turned on in production. Then you would be compiling assets on request, which is *not* how the asset pipeline is meant to work. That setting should be *off* in production, and you should be relying on statically compiled assets.

Typically your `public` folder, where your compiled assets reside, should be shared across all of your deploys, via symlink for example, so that pages requesting older assets are able to find them.

Comment: Thanks for the response! `config.assets.compile` is set to false (actually it's not set at all). We're using Heroku and old assets are not kept. 404 is the behavior I would expect but it's definitely returning something, sometimes 503 because the asset takes too long to compile and it times out.

Comment: I don't have an answer on why I was seeing this behavior, but during debugging I noticed that we were still using sprockets 2. After upgrading to sprockets 3 non precompiled assets correctly return a 404.